# Как правильно настроить htaccess что бы создавать нужные url?

Tags: php

На данный момент мой
.htaccess содержит

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Если я правильно понимаю то q=$1 позволяет создавать такие url site.ru/categories/1
А как правильно настроить что бы я мог создавать url такого рода site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/categories/1/1
и такого site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/categories/1/1/1
По url /categories/1 буду получать одну категорию, по url /categories/1/1 буду получать все товары этой категории, а по url /categories/1/1/1 один товар этой категории

index.php

```
<?php

header('Content-type: json/application');
require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

$q = ($_GET['q']);
$params = explode('/', $q);

$type = $params[0];
$id = $params[1];

if($type === 'typs'){
    
    if(isset($id)){
        getTyp($connect, $id);
    } else{
        getTyps($connect);
    }
}

$categorie = $params[0];
$id = $params[1];

if($categorie === 'categories'){
    
    if(isset($id)){
        getCategorie($connect, $id);
    } else{
        getCategories($connect);
    }
}

?>
```

На данный момент url такого рода site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/categories/1/1/1
получается сделать, но он идентичен с url site.ru/api/appfaucetlist/categories/1
То есть от сервера я получаю одну и ту самую информацию

Comment: `$1` это ссылка на группу захвата, которая у вас в скобках в шаблонен указана. То есть в `$_GET['q']` вы будете получить входящую урл, если такового нет среди файлов в корне сайта. Дальше разделяйте логику свою на уровне пхп кода, смотря что там у вас пришло. В общем говоря вопрос не совсем ясен, вы спрашивайте про htaccess, но он пробрасывает все ссылки. Дальше уже стройте бизнеслогику соответствующую.

Comment: ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f``` - если это условие срабатывает (не существует файла по заданному пути), то вас кидает на правило ниже. Вам нужно добавить еще одно - проверять существование директории ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d```. Кроме того, рекомендую посмотреть проект на гитхабе как раз по разбору роутов, весьма удобно реализовано https://github.com/bramus/router/

Comment: Ну а как мне тогда сделать что бы после /1/1 находилось то что мне нужно? Просто после того как я делаю такого рода url я получаю тот же ответ по get запросу что и по url /1